# Kenmore dishwasher - replaced broken heating element but still not fully drying

Tags: dishwasher

I have a Kenmore dishwasher, model `665.13073K210`.  It also reads `13073K 583-0` inside the door.  Some time ago I noticed that dishes were not getting dry like they had been, and after the cycle finished it wasn't as hot inside. I saw that there was a little nodule looking thing on the heating element and determined I needed to replace the heating element.

I replaced the element this weekend with a new one, ran everything through with what appeared to be no problems.  But it still does not seem to be drying well still.  After some further reading it sounds like maybe I might have to replace a thermostat and/or a thermal fuse, too?  As those might have been damaged or something when the heating element original broke?

What should I look for from here? Is there both a thermostat and a fuse and which should I check first? I'm honestly not looking forward to taking the whole unit back out so I'm hoping that whatever I'm checking might be inside the door panel.

Comment: This may sound simple but when you push the heated dry button can you feel a click or movment?

Comment: I do not, but then again I don't recall ever hearing or feeling any clicking noises when pressing the button in the past.

Comment: Do the rest of the switches feel similar? I wonder if the switch is either off or malfunctioning.

Comment: All the switches on the front panel feel the same, and as far as I can tell they feel/act the same as they always have.  I've never noticed any clicking sounds when pressing them. The indicator light comes on when I press the "heated dry" button and nothing indicates any errors.  Which is what made me wonder if there was something causing the new element to just not engage. I don't see any indication of the new element being broken, either.